# Integral over a surface in 4-dimensions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, surface-integrals

Consider the integral of a function $f(x,y,z)$ over a surface embedded in 3 dimensions. 
The surface has a parameterization:
$$g(u,v) = (x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v)) $$
The integral is given by:

$$ \iint_{u,v}f(g(u,v))\|\vec{g}_u \times \vec{g}_v\|\,dudv$$

In words, you are placing a curvilinear coordinate system over the surface (a "form-fitting" coordinate system to the surface). You use these curvilinear grid lines to tile the surface with parallelogram area elements. These parallelograms are actually linear approximations to the curvilinear area elements.

**Question**

Consider a surface integral of a function $f(x,y,z,w)$ over a surface embedded in 4 dimensions. The surface has a parameterization:
$$ g(u,v) = (x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v), w(u,v)) $$

The integral is given by
$$ \iint_{u,v} f(g(u,v))(\;\;\;\;)dudv$$
I can embedded parallelograms in 4 dimensions. However my question is, *what is the notation used for the linear approximation?* The cross product doesn't work in 4-dimensions. So I was wondering if I should go back to something more geometric: $A = bh$. The two side lengths of an infinitesimal parallelogram are given by $\|\vec{g}_u\|du$ and $\|\vec{g}_v\|dv$. The angle between them is given by

$$ \theta = \arccos\Big(\frac{\vec{g}_udu \cdot \vec{g}_vdv}{\|\vec{g}_u\|du\|\vec{g}_v\|dv}\Big) \\
\theta = \arccos\Big(\frac{\vec{g}_u \cdot \vec{g}_v}{\|\vec{g}_u\|\|\vec{g}_v\|}\Big)
$$
And therefore my integral becomes

$$ \iint_{u,v} f(g(u,v)) \|\vec{g}_u\|\|\vec{g}_v\|\sin(\arccos\Big(\frac{\vec{g}_u \cdot \vec{g}_v}{\|\vec{g}_u\|\|\vec{g}_v\|}\Big)) \,dudv$$

Is this even correct? If so, is there simplifying notation for the linear approximation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is another way to think about the quantity $\left| g_u \times g_v \right|$ which will generalize to more than three dimensions. If $g(u,v) = (x(u,v), \, y(u,v), \, z(u,v))$, then the cross product, in components, is

$$ g_u \times g_v = (y_u z_v - y_v z_u, \, z_u x_v - z_v x_u, \, x_u y_v - x_v y_u) $$

Its squared norm is

$$
\begin {align*}
\left| g_u \times g_v \right|^2 &= (y_u z_v - y_v z_u)^2 + (z_u x_v - z_v x_u)^2 + (x_u y_v - x_v y_u)^2 \\
&= (y_u z_v)^2 + (y_v z_u)^2 + (z_u x_v)^2 + (z_v x_u)^2 + (x_u y_v)^2 + (x_v y_u)^2 \\
&\phantom{=} - 2 \left( y_uy_vz_uz_v + z_uz_vx_ux_v + x_ux_vy_uy_v \right)
\end {align*}
$$

A quick computation will convince you that this is equal to

$$ \left| g_u \right|^2 \left| g_v \right|^2 - \left( g_u \cdot g_v \right)^2 $$

So in conclusion, we can think of this area element quantity as

$$ \left| g_u \times g_v \right| = \sqrt{\left| g_u \right|^2 \left| g_v \right|^2 - \left( g_u \cdot g_v \right)^2} $$

This is also the square root of the determinant of the matrix

$$ G = \left( \begin{array}{cc} g_u \cdot g_u & g_u \cdot g_v \\ g_v \cdot g_u & g_v \cdot g_v \end{array} \right) $$

Now this approach should give you the correct area element for surfaces embedded in higher dimensional space. In your example of a surface in $\Bbb{R}^4$, with $g(u,v) = (x,y,z,w)$, it still makes sense to consider

$$ g_u = (x_u,y_u,z_u,w_u) $$
$$ g_v = (x_v,y_v,z_v,w_v) $$

They are now just 4-dimensional vectors. The area element will still be the square root of the determinant of the matrix $G$ above.

To explain why this approach works you need to know some differential geometry, including the theory of differential forms and Riemannian metrics, so I will just leave it at that.